# Why does my 16x2 LCD displays weird letters and can't insert key from keypad?

Tags: lcd, adafruit, eeprom, wire-library, keypad

I'm a newbie on Arduino here, and this is my first project on 16x2 LCD, 4x4 keypad and others. So, the story is, after I uploaded the program for my group's Arduino alarm clock to the Arduino board, the LCD displays black boxes on the first row of the LCD. But after soldering the LCD pins again and connect the Vo to the 10k ohm potentiometer, the LCD can display the "welcome" part properly. This can be seen in the two pictures below.
[image: Welcome To]

[image: TIMe Project]
However, after a while, there are weird letters appearing on the second row of the LCD, blinking from the first picture below to the second picture again and again. Plus, I couldn't input any key from the keypad to the LCD, since the display's stuck at there.
[image: weird letters show up]

[image: weird letters show up again]
I'm not sure if there's any problem in the circuit or in the programming. I'm quite confused here. Below is the code I uploaded to the Arduino board. Thank you in advance.

```cpp
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <DS1307.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

DS1307 rtc(SDA, SCL);
LiquidCrystal lcd(A3, A2, A1, A0, 5, 4);
Time t;

#define buz 3

int Hor, Min, Sec, h, m, s;
int ASCII = 48;
char* tim;
char* dat;
const char key = 0;
char buffer[2];
const byte numRows= 4;
const byte numCols= 4;
char keymap[numRows][numCols]=
{
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};
byte rowPins[numRows] = {12, 11, 10, 9};
byte colPins[numCols]= {8, 7, 6, 5};
Keypad myKeypad= Keypad(makeKeymap(keymap),rowPins, colPins, numRows, numCols);

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  rtc.begin();
  pinMode(buz, OUTPUT);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  welcome();

  rtc.setDOW(SATURDAY); //Set Day-of-Week to SUNDAY
  rtc.setTime(10, 54, 0); //Set the time to 12:00:00     (24hr format)
  rtc.setDate(7, 1, 2017); //Day, Month, Year
}

void loop() {
  t = rtc.getTime();
  Hor = t.hour;
  Min = t.min;
  Sec = t.sec;
  tim = rtc.getTimeStr();
  dat = rtc.getDateStr();
  char key = myKeypad.getKey();

  if (key == 'C'){
    digitalWrite(buz, LOW);
    EEPROM.write(2, ASCII+6);
    EEPROM.write(3, ASCII);
  }

  if(key == '#'){
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Enter New Time");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    int j =0;
    int i=0;
    while( j<6)
    {
      if(i==2 || i == 5){
        lcd.print(":");
        lcd.display();
        i++;
      }
      key=myKeypad.getKey();
      if(key)
      {
        lcd.print(key);
        lcd.display();
        EEPROM.write(j,key);
        j++;
        i++;
      }
    }
  }

  changealarm();
  checkalarm();
  timedate();
}

void checkalarm(){
  if( Hor == h && Min == m)
  {
    delay(3000);
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Hold C");
    digitalWrite(buz, HIGH);
    delay(3000);
  }
}

void changealarm(){
  buffer[0]=EEPROM.read(0);
  buffer[1]=EEPROM.read(1);
  h = atoi(buffer);
  buffer[0]=EEPROM.read(2);
  buffer[1]=EEPROM.read(3);
  m = atoi(buffer);
  buffer[0]=EEPROM.read(4);
  buffer[1]=EEPROM.read(5);
  s = atoi(buffer);
}

void timedate(){
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Time: ");
  lcd.print(rtc.getTimeStr());

  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Date: ");
  lcd.print(rtc.getDateStr());
  delay(3000);
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Alarm: ");
  lcd.print(h);
  lcd.print(".");
  lcd.print(m);
  lcd.print(".");
  lcd.print(s);
  delay(3000);
}

void welcome(){
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Welcome");

  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("To");
  delay(3000);

  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("TIMeProject");
  delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: Which of the many DS1307 libraries are you using in paricular?

Comment: I use DS1307 library from this website http://www.rinkydinkelectronics.com/library.php?id=34

Comment: Only a beginner would try to make a full project work. An more experienced programmer makes a small part and test if it works, and then another part and so on. You could make a small sketch to test the buttons for example. A text has a zero terminator. Make your buffer 10 or 16 or 40, but not just size 2. Set buffer[2] to '\0' before calling atoi. The 'key' is printed on the display, I think that is what you see.

Comment: I've already changed the `changealarm()` code according to jose can u c's solution, but the weird letters are still there. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

In your `changealarm()` function, you call `atoi(buffer)`, and `buffer` is defined as `char buffer[2]`.

`atoi()` expects a c-style string, which is null-terminated, and you have to include space for the null termination character (`'\0'`, `0`, `0x00`, etc.), but you write to both allocated spaces in the `changealarm()` function. If your 2nd byte of each EEPROM space (1, 3, 5) is non-zero, then your have an unterminated string.

`atoi()` expects a null-terminated string, and so the behavior is unexpected. Probably `atoi()` is running into other memory. If the string being sent is not representable by a `int` type, then the behavior of `atoi()` is *undefined*.

---

A quick fix would be to increase the size of `buffer` and guarantee null termination:

```
char buffer[3];  // Make the buffer 3 bytes long
[...]
void changealarm() {
  buffer[2]=0;   // Set the 3rd byte to zero to null-terminate

  buffer[0]=EEPROM.read(0);
  buffer[1]=EEPROM.read(1);
  h = atoi(buffer);
  buffer[0]=EEPROM.read(2);
  buffer[1]=EEPROM.read(3);
  m = atoi(buffer);
  buffer[0]=EEPROM.read(4);
  buffer[1]=EEPROM.read(5);
  s = atoi(buffer);
}
```

Comment: I see. But what's I'm supposed to do? Should I change the atoi() part? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I updated my answer to show a solution to the overflow problem. (There are other problems in your code, too, like a lot of 3000ms delays where nothing can happen; not even keypad presses)

Comment: I've changed the `changealarm()` part according to your solution. And I've tried to change the delays to 1000ms. But still, the same display occurs. So, I'm guessing, there's something wrong at the `if(key == '#') ...` part?

Comment: How long after the sketch starts does the junk display occur? Does it occur if you press no keys at all?

Comment: After I changed the delays to 1000ms, the junk display occurs a second after the `lcd.print("TIMeProject");` display. It keeps on blinking the junk display automatically. And yes, it occurs if I press no keys at all, right after I uploaded the code to the board.

Comment: The weird letters displayed problems are solved! It turns out that the keypad pins were connected differently with the code uploaded.